# SQL - Count number of rows with the same value without displaying the Count

Tags: mysql

How can I Count number of rows with the same value of `a.customer` in the Selected table, but I do not want to display the Count, just to display the Selected rows and Limit the display to the Top 3 from the Count. I have the code like this:

```
    SELECT a.number, b.product, 
    x.descp, b.serial, a.customer
    FROM a 
    LEFT JOIN b
    ON a.number = b.number
    LEFT JOIN x
    ON b.product = x.product
    LEFT JOIN d
    ON a.stat = d.stat
    WHERE d.prmt = 'ABC'
    AND a.date >= 20210528
    AND a.date <= 20210530
```

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() in CTE and according WHERE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the counts and a ROW_NUMBER(only available in newer Versions) to the hole select

```
SELECT a.number, b.product, 
    x.descp, b.serial, a.customer
    FROM a 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT 
    a.customer, COUNT(*) countr, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
FROM
    a
        LEFT JOIN
    b ON a.number = b.number
        LEFT JOIN
    x ON b.product = x.product
        LEFT JOIN
    d ON a.stat = d.stat
WHERE
    d.prmt = 'ABC' AND a.date >= 20210528
        AND a.date <= 20210530
GROUP BY a.customer) t1 ON t1.customer = a.customer
    LEFT JOIN b
    ON a.number = b.number
    LEFT JOIN x
    ON b.product = x.product
    LEFT JOIN d
    ON a.stat = d.stat
    WHERE d.prmt = 'ABC'
    AND a.date >= 20210528
    AND a.date <= 20210530
    AND rn <= 3
```